# Is it possible to get a prototype bean from Spring Context without creating a new bean every time?

Tags: spring

I have a servlet that it needs to get information from a prototype bean. However, I don't want to get a new bean the servlet is running. As for now, I still couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: Do you understand what a prototype bean is?

Comment: I do. Just trying to know if I can achieve that under certain circumstances..

Comment: Prototype bean = new instance every time.

Answer (score 0):

In spring, beans are of two basic types, singletons or prototypes. If you have a singleton, which is the default, then spring will create one instance as the application context is booted, and all references to this bean will return this single instance. If the bean is a prototype, then all references to it will be fulfilled with a new instance per reference.

However, your question is ambiguous. If you mean that you have a bean which is, generally, a prototype, but that for a special usage you want to treat it as if its a singleton, then why not create two beans, of the same type, one as a singleton and one as a prototype, and use a qualifier to distinguish the two.